# Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. Using typescript and compose from react-apollo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo, react-apollo

I'm using typescript and `react-apollo`

my code is the following:
[image]

If I remove the last `(Index)` the error will go away but I have no idea on how then export the container/component.

Basically, the code works but typescript is not happy with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imprecisely defining `compose` parameters as `any` will satisfy the compiler.

```
export default compose<any>(
  ...
)(Index)
```

Answer (score 1):

For others struggling with a similar issue.

Defining a separate generic compose function also will work and can then just be invoked immediately without issue.

```
const invokableCompose = <any>compose;

export default invokeableCompose(fn1, fn2)(Index);
```